# Best practice leads to bloated containers and non modular code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I’ve been told that it’s a best practice to use classes only for containers and to use functions for components. So containers have state and components are dumb functions that only recieve and send props to and from the containers.

The problem I’m finding with this is that it leads to really bloated containers. Not only that but if a container includes many different components then the methods in these containers are a mixture of many different unrelated functionalities.

This goes against the idea of keeping everything very modular. For example if I have a “submit comment” component in my container I would expect the submitCommentHandler method to also be in the relevant component not mixed together in the Post container with a ton of other handlers for unrelated functionalities like being next to the ratePostHandler and the userLoginHandler.

I’m new to react so maybe I’m missing something but how to reconcile this “best practice” with all the other issues it presents?

Comment: First of all, container component doesn't have to contain business logic. Even if it has submitCommentHandler method, it can be as concise as `submitCommentHandler(comment) => this.commentService.add(comment)`. Also, this is a problem that state management libs like Redux address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of misconceptions in your post, possibly stemming from misconceptions in whatever best practices article you are reading.

When the core idea of containers + components started surfacing many examples were not doing it correctly.

```
// DO NOT DO THIS

let FormComponent = ({ data, handleSubmit }) =>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    {...something with data...}
  </form>

class FormContainer extends React.Component {
  state = { data: [] }
  submitForm = formData => {
    api.post(formData).then(data => this.setState({ data }))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormComponent 
          data={this.state.data} 
          handleSubmit={this.submitForm} 
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is a pretty classic container + component example, however it's **100% useless** and goes against the entire idea. In order for containers to be modular they need to be **completely agnostic** about render logic. If you hardcode the presentation in the container, then it's all just one big component split into two sections, somewhat arbitrarily I might add.

You can read about higher order components, but I'm going to focus on standard that's gaining traction: [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

```
class FormContainer extends React.Component {
  state = { data: [] }
  submitForm = formData => {
    api.post(formData).then(data => this.setState({ data }))
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.children({ 
      data: this.state.data, 
      submitForm: this.submitForm 
    })
  }
}
```

Now you have a container that does one thing, that can be used repeatedly anywhere in your app, with any presentational component like so:

```
let SomewhereInYourApp = () => (
  <FormContainer>
    {({ data, submitForm }) => (
      <div> 
       {/* put whatever you want here.. it's modular! */}
       <FormComponent data={data} handleSubmit={submitForm} />
      </div>
    )}
  </FormContainer>      
)
```

Then you can make as many containers as you need which only do the specific business logic that's important to it and nest them however it makes sense to do so. I don't think any best practices say to combine everything into a single container. Nesting containers is perfectly acceptable.

If you have many containers and the nesting gets a little too pyramidy, consider using HoCs or a utility like [react-adopt](https://github.com/pedronauck/react-adopt) to compose containers that use render props.

Screenshot of composed containers from react-adopt:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I need to dig into this path a bit more but I think I understood your example.